# website is https ssl certified but the port isn't?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I created a certificate for a website hoping that the port number would also be certified. Maybe I'm not understanding how this works exactly but, I'll explain the problem exactly.

The website is called https://xxxxx.com . When you access it, you do see that it is a certified website.

The website is hosted on ec2 aws AMI 1.

The website contains a node server than when activated is started on port 3002.

When I try to go to https://xxxxx.com:3002 I receive an error:

`ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

I'm close to fixing my problem. I originally couldn't even get the certificate uploaded for the website. I've been at this thing for almost a whole week. I'm definitely close. Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Does it have to do with the apache configuration files?

Comment: Ports arent a part of SSL certificate verification, full stop.  The certificate merely verifies based on the domain name and the certificate authority's validity.

Comment: sounds like a hard stop to me. So am I correct in looking into apache port configurations?

Comment: `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` suggests that whatever is listening on port 3002 isn't speaking HTTPS. It's probably a plain HTTP server.

Comment: "Does it have to do with the apache configuration files?" — You said the Node server was listening on port 3002. Since the client is talking to the Node server and not the Apache server … no. Well, not unless you wrote JavaScript to read the Apache config files and do something with them in Node.

Comment: Should I be creating another certificate specifically for port 3002?

Comment: Is that the real domain name?

Answer (score -1):

> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

That means nodejs isn't speaking ssl.  Be careful making assumptions about what erorrs mean; down that path lies many a wild goose chase.

> I created a certificate for a website hoping that the port number would also be certified

Ports arent a part of SSL certificate verification, full stop.  The certificate verifies based on the domain name and the certificate authority's validity.  Any service with that cert accessed on that domain name will verify, regardless of the port.

> The website contains a node server than when activated is started on port 3002.

Typically this kind of setup has Apache listnening on https://0.0.0.0:443 for https, then redirecting the appropriate traffic to NodeJS listening on *http:*//127.0.0.1:3002.   You probably wouldn't want the Node server internet-facing.   But if you do, and node supports TLS (looks like it does), you would have to give a cert to NodeJS and tell it to speak HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Comment: holy crap. I had no idea that this was going to be so difficult. 


So I need to redirect from https://0.0.0.0:443 to https://xxx:3002. I have no idea where to begin on that.

Comment: So I have to set the outbound of my ec2 server to the right port. AFTER that in my node.js code I have to listen to port 443 right?